# Error reading XMLStreamReader by django request

Tags: django, xml, soap, django-rest-framework, python-requests

My xml data:

```
xml_payload = 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
        <Authentication >
            <username>blabla</username>
            <password>123456789</password>
        </Authentication>
    </soap:Header>
        <soap:Body>
            <data>
                <title>Test title</title>
                <content>Test body format</content>
            </data>
        </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My request in django project:

```
try:
    url = "http://someurls.com"
    res = requests.post(url=url, data=xml_payload, headers={'Content-type': 'application/xml'})
    return response.content, response.status_code
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    return None, 500
```

When i hit the request using postman then i get response is given bellow:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Body>
        <soap:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>Error reading XMLStreamReader.</faultstring>
        </soap:Fault>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'
```

It returns an error. I am surfing around the internet but didn't find any answer which is fulfilled my query.

Comment: It can be a params (params=xml_payload) ?

Comment: @MatteoBianchi No

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the xml payload as follows:

```py
xml_payload = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap:Header>
        <Authentication >
            <username>blabla</username>
            <password>123456789</password>
        </Authentication>
    </soap:Header>
        <soap:Body>
            <data>
                <title>Test title</title>
                <content>Test body format</content>
            </data>
        </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Afterd days, i finally found the answer. When i create a xml payload by python then python invisibly add "\n" at the end of every line. So when i replaced those "\n" then i works perfectly.

```
xml_payload = xml_payload.replace("\n", "")
```